# Pandas setting column values to adjacent ones for duplicates found in a key column

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming we have the following table:

```
+---------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| COL_ID  | ColB | COLC | COLD | COLE | COLF | COLG | COLH | COLI |
+---------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| aa1     |    1 |    1 |      |      |      |      |      |      |
| aa1     | 2    |    1 |      |      |      |      |      |      |
| aa2     |    3 |    1 |      |      |      |      |      |      |
| ab3     |    6 |    2 |      |      |      |      |      |      |
| ab3     |    5 |    2 |      |      |      |      |      |      |
| ab3     |    7 |    1 |      |      |      |      |      |      |
| ab3     |    1 |    1 |      |      |      |      |      |      |
+---------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

How can we assign the values of duplicates in the adjacent column if a duplicate is found?

```
+---------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| COL_ID  | ColB | COLC | COLD | COLE | COLF | COLG | COLH | COLI |
+---------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| aa1     |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |    2 |    1 |      |      |
| aa2     |    3 |    1 |      |      |      |      |      |      |
| ab3     |    6 |    2 |    5 |    2 |    7 |    1 |    1 |    1 |
+---------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Here is the sample code to generate this table

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


my_dic =  {'COL_ID': ['aa1', 'aa1', 'aa2', 'ab3','ab3','ab3','ab3'],
'COLB': [1,2,3,6,5,7,1],
'COLC': [1,1,1,2,2,1,1],
'COLD':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
'COLF':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
'COLG':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
'COLH':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
'COLI:':[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]}
    
dp = pd.DataFrame(my_dic)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is use lambda function for all columns without `COL_ID` converted to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), create default index by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for new columns names, last reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with converting to integers with missing values by `Int64`:

```
dp = (dp.set_index('COL_ID')
        .groupby('COL_ID')
        .apply(lambda x: x.stack().reset_index(drop=True))
        .unstack()
        .astype('Int64')
        .add_prefix('Col')
        .reset_index())
print (dp)
  COL_ID  Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7
0    aa1     1     1     2     1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
1    aa2     3     1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2    ab3     6     2     5     2     7     1     1     1
```

Another idea:

```
s = dp.set_index('COL_ID').stack().droplevel(1)
counter = s.groupby('COL_ID').cumcount().to_numpy()
s.index = [s.index, counter]

dp = s.unstack().astype('Int64').add_prefix('Col').reset_index()
print (dp)
  COL_ID  Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7
0    aa1     1     1     2     1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
1    aa2     3     1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2    ab3     6     2     5     2     7     1     1     1
```

Comment: how can we remove the grouping here? - Nvm you have updated your answer.

Comment: wow how long have you been in the industry? any tips on how to learn building logics like these?

Comment: @Led - `wow how long have you been in the industry` - I think at least 5 years. `any tips on how to learn building logics like these?` - coding a lot time, not easy way in my opinion. Or you have coding gift (not me, for me it was/is really hard)

Comment: by the way, can this be applied to thousand of records?

Comment: @Led - I think yes, second solution should be faster/ better for larger data

Comment: yep confirmed, the second one was way faster. Thank you very much